# Convolution of two delta distributions

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Show ${\int}_0^{\infty}\delta(x+z)\delta(y-z)dz =\delta(y+x)$

It seems obvious, and I don't think we need a rigorous proof for this (statistical mechanics homework) but I want a rigorous proof of this anyway. I found something about 'nascent dirac delta' functions forming a semigroup under convolution on wikipedia, but I'm not good enough to use that, plus it's stated without proof. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Semigroups

Comment: Replace one of the two $\delta$s with a Gaussian and take the variance (limit) to $0$ on both sides

Comment: Integrate the integral expression against a test function $f$ either in $x$ or in $z$. Then you can reduce everything to integrals.

Comment: $\large\delta\left(y + x\right)\Theta\left(y\right)$ where $\large\Theta\left(y\right)$ is the [Heaviside Step Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) .

Comment: @FelixMarin what do you mean by your comment?

Comment: That is the answer to your question.

Comment: @FelixMarin Do you mean my statement is incorrect? I'm looking for a proof, do you mean y is strictly positive for it to hold true?

Comment: Yes. $\delta\left(z - y\right)$ is 'centered' at $y$. It means that $z > 0$ in order to have a non-zero result since the integration is performed along $\left(0,\infty\right)$.